# Compiling FFMpeg for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

A lot of people have mentioned about compiling ffmpeg for android. But I recently tried many of them and did not find them working.

Here is what I tried.

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

but in this I got the following errors.

```
/home/musil/Desktop/android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/musil/Desktop/android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-3/arch-arm -I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mcpu=cortex-a8 -c -o /tmp/ffconf.6LOSva5W.o /tmp/ffconf.YWZ9ftQ8.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
C compiler test failed.
```

Than I have tried other way mentioned on

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

but in that I got the following error.

But in that the prefix install is **/usr/local/** instead of **./arm/** and arch is x86 instead of arm. And it compiles but no arm folder is created.

Does anyone know how to compile ffmpeg for ndk-r10c.

Will be very helpful if someone can point out what I am doing wrong or how can I build the **ffmpeg 2.4.1** for latest ndk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you see that error. I was able to successfully compile FFMpeg and you should be able to get the .so files for all architecture from this link https://github.com/android-native-libraries

Comment: Did you build it using ndk-r10c and the latest ffmpeg version. Or you build it using the old versions mentioned on the links.

Comment: These were compiled with ndk-r9.